# Azure File Storage deletion calculation

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-files

I am trying to delete Files out of the Azure File Storage that are that are 30 + 1 on the first day of the month or older.
I have basic list and remove script that works. My main question is how do I do a calculation for a if older than statement?

```
$resourceGroupName=""  
$storageAccName=""  
$fileShareName=""  
$directoryPath="" 
## Function to Lists directories and files  
Function GetFiles  
{  
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Lists directories and files.."    
    ## Get the storage account context  
    $ctx=(Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccName).Context  
    ## List directories  
    $directories=Get-AZStorageFile -Context $ctx -ShareName $fileShareName  
    ## Loop through directories  
    foreach($directory in $directories)  
    {  
        write-host -ForegroundColor Magenta " Directory Name: " $directory.Name  
        $files=Get-AZStorageFile -Context $ctx -ShareName $fileShareName -Path $directory.Name | Get-AZStorageFile  
        ## Loop through all files and display  
        foreach ($file in $files)  
        {  
            write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow $file.Name  
        }  
    }  
}  
  
GetFiles
$context = ""
Remove-AzStorageFile -ShareName "name" -Path "path" -Context $context

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: You can always get the first of the month with `[datetime]::Today.AddDays(([datetime]::Today.Day - 1)*-1)`. I'm not familiar with the term '30 + 1'. Are you just looking for files that are over a month old? Maybe `$file.properties.changetime -lt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(([datetime]::Today.Day - 1)*-1).addmonths(-1)` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do have AZ CLI command to delete files older than XX days.

// Delete old files block

```
$filelist = az storage file list -s $myshare --account-name $accountName --account-key $accountKey
$fileArray = $filelist | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($file in $fileArray | Where-Object {$_.properties.lastModified.DateTime -lt ((Get-Date).AddDays(-31))})
{
    $removefile = $file.name
    if ($removefile -ne $null)
    {
        Write-Host "Removing file $removefile"
        az storage file delete -s $myshare -p $removefile
    }
}
```

Reference So Thread: Use Azure Cli to Delete Old Files in Azure file share - Stack Overflow